# How to delete Game Request using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am following facebook [Game Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#handlingrequestsingame) docs and it ain't working.

When I read from `me/apprequests?fields=id,from`, I am getting the next response.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"195821120786554_103530083376255",
         "from":{
            "name":"Donna Alaadbchchbai Thurnwitz",
            "id":"140672792990181"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"1739292086315402_103530083376255",
         "from":{
            "name":"Mike Alaaehejgahib Zuckerwitz",
            "id":"102765500119619"
         }
      }
   ],
   "paging":{
      "cursors":{
         "before":"MTk1ODIxMTIwNzg2NTU0OjEwMDAxMTU4NTA3MTg5MgZDZD",
         "after":"MTk1ODIxMTIwNzg2NTU0OjEwMDAxMTU4NTA3MTg5MgZDZD"
      }
   }
}
```

Now I been trying two ways to delete those requests and both return error

> (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:

I been testing this in GraphExploere

1. Endpoint: `[195821120786554_103530083376255,1739292086315402_103530083376255]`
2. Endpoint: `[195821120786554_103530083376255_140672792990181,1739292086315402_103530083376255_102765500119619]`

> Game Requests are not automatically deleted after they have been
>   accepted by the recipient. It is the responsibility of the developer
>   to delete the request after it has been accepted. You must delete
>   requests on behalf of players once they have been accepted.
>
> You can delete a request via the following methods:
>
> Graph API
>
> Issue an HTTP DELETE request to the concatenated request_id:
>
> DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[{REQUEST_OBJECT_ID}_{USER_ID}]?
>         access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]

So what should I do?

Comment: What exactly does your request look like? Your `[id1,id2]` “endpoint” syntax doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[id1,id2]?access_token. This is what I understand from docs.

Comment: You need to delete them one at a time (or use the ?ids=… syntax, that might also work to delete multiple requests at once.)

Comment: @CBroe Great, can you please show me an example how to use the ?ids... syntax.

Comment: ?ids=id1,id2 – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#multiidlookup (not sure if that will work here though)